# Is it possible to add constant column during join in bash command?

Tags: bash, join

I have 2 input files

file1

```
A   0.01
B   0.09
D   0.05
F   0.08
```

file2

```
A   0.03
C   0.01
D   0.04
E   0.09
```

The output I want is

```
A   0.01    0.03    1
B   0.09    NULL    1
C   NULL    0.01    1
D   0.05    0.04    1
E   NULL    0.09    1
F   0.08    NULL    1
```

This is what I did so far

```
join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2,'1' file1 file2
```

which gave me

```
join: invalid field specifier: `1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use join for this, there are zillions of tools that can do that for you, eg:

```
sed 's/$/\t1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be more elegant and flexible solutions in Perl, Python or Ruby. A Bash solution is shown below as per your requirement.

- File contents are considered separated by TAB (otherwise change `-d` for `cut`).
- It is not clear how you derive your fourth column in the output. Therefore, I ignored it.
- Not sure if `sed 's/$/\t1/g'` is what you want. As, you'd probably get rows with same first element (e.g. two rows with `A` and `D`). Your example output seeks unique columns with aggregated values for each key.

**Execution:**

```
babil@host:~$ cat file1
A   0.01
B   0.09
D   0.05
F   0.08
babil@host:~$ cat file2
A   0.03
C   0.01
D   0.04
E   0.09
babil@host:~$ ./t.sh 
A   0.01    0.03    1
B   0.09    NULL    1
C   NULL    0.01    1
D   0.05    0.04    1
E   NULL    0.09    1
F   0.08    NULL    1
babil@norbit:~$
```

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash 

F1="file1"
F2="file2"

keys=$(cut -d $'\t' -f1 $F1 $F2 | sort -u)

for k in $keys
do
        v1=$(grep $k $F1 | cut -f2 -d $'\t')
        if [[ $v1 == "" ]]
        then
                v1="NULL"
        fi
        v2=$(grep $k $F2 | cut -f2 -d $'\t')
        if [[ $v2 == "" ]]
        then
                v2="NULL"
        fi
        echo -e "$k\t$v1\t$v2\t1"
done
```